# Cacerts file not applied to TrustStore when running on Linux

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I'm having trouble setting the path of the cacerts file to the TrustStore in Linux environment, in Windows runs smoothly.

It is a Spring project, the cacerts file is inside the resources folder, I inform the cacerts path to the **javax.net.ssl.trustStore** by code and I create the **.war** file with the command **mvn clean package** and in linux, when executing the .war, error occurs when trying to connect with the AD Ldap server, I believe the problem is the cacerts that was not found.

My code to inform the cacerts:

```
Path keystore = null;
try {
    keystore = Files.createTempFile(null, null);

    InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cacerts");

    Files.copy(stream, keystore, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(keystore.toString()); // print path 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore.toString());
```

**System.out.println(keystore.toString())** shows the path of the file in **/tmp** and when checking with an **ls -l** the file appears in the listing, is it some problem with the Linux environment or is it some code question that should be otherwise worked?

**Edited:**
The error that appears on the linux server:

> org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: 172.16.0.12:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: 172.16.0.12:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 172.16.0.12 found]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be a code issue.

Some of the JVM properties are used by code that is triggered by static initialization.  In this case, the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property is used the first time that something tries to access the default trusted keystore or the default set of trusted X509 certs.  It is not clear when this happens.

So, there is a fair chance that your call to `System.setProperty` is happening too late; i.e. after it has been used.

Try setting the property using a `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=...` command line option and see if that works.

---

**UPDATE**

> I've tried with -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore, it did not work well because it worked "only when it wanted", 10 attempts one worked, approximately! It even that using the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore can happen to delay the application of cacerts? On the way this code is executed, the method is an @Bean(name="contextSource") inside an @Configuration class. How can I make to run at the right time?

At least this demonstrates that if you use `-D`, the property is set early enough to be available.  This proves that the *mechanism* is not broken!

The problem now will be that your custom `TrustStore` **file** is being used before app has had a chance to create it.  (You could test this ...)

My guess is that it is the web container initilization that is triggering this.  I don't think you can make it work<sup>1</sup>.  Instead, you need to address the custom TrustStore requirement in another way:

- Add a separate deployment step to extract your custom TrustStore to a file in the file system *before you start the web container*.
- Alternatively, change the webapp or web container to not rely on the default TrustStore mechanism.

To answer your follow up question: as far as I can tell, there isn't.  The Java security code is not designed to allow instantiation of the default TrustStore to be delayed, or to allow it to be changed.  Look at the source code!!

---

<sup>1 - Even if you could set the property before the web container initializes and tries to use the TrustStore, you need to first create the TrustStore from a webapp resource.  The classloader for that resource is created by webcontainer, during or after the webcontainer initialization.  It is most likely to be too complicated to get the steps to reliably happen in the order that you need them to.</sup>

Comment: I've tried with -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore, it did not work well because it worked "only when it wanted", 10 attempts one worked, approximately!
It even that using the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore can happen to delay the application of cacerts?
On the way this code is executed, the method is an `@Bean(name="contextSource")` inside an `@Configuration` class. How can I make to run at the right time?

Comment: I used -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore option and in the method I was trying to set the cacerts file I commented the code and put the command `System.out.println(System.getProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"))` , appeared in the terminal "/backend-source/cacerts", that is, it found the file.
However, the error `[Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 172.16.0.12 found`. Is this because there is no host name for this address?

Comment: That is a different question.

Comment: Ok, the question of adding the cacerts worked out, I'll try to solve the new error!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

About the problem with IP, I was able to resolve it by adding the paramter at the time of executing the .war file.

```
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true
```